# Reactjs and AWS Amplify - error generating

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-amplify

I am using aws amplify using my reactjs website from my github repository. It seems to work until now, I have an error at the "generate" step. However I can't see any log, and I don't understand where it is coming from. can you help me finding the logs of this error ?
Thank you !

[image]